# Facebook not always asking user for extended permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, permissions

I'm trying to get `access_token` with extended permissions using Facebook SDK for .NET. 
I do a redirect from my website to oauth login dialog with url
`http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={my client id}&redirect_uri={my redirect url}&scope=manage_pages,publish_pages,publish_actions&state={guid state}`
(I checked in the browser, the `scope` parameter exists in the URL).
And for some users it asks for extended permissions after the first permission window and for some users it doesn't.
After redirected back, I do a request using received `code` and get `access_token`. I check the received token in token debugger and for those users, who were asked for special permissions, the token Scopes contain required extended permissions and for those who were not asked, it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot ask other users than the app's admins/testers/developers for extended permissions until these have been granted to your app during the Login Review process.

I suspect that you didn't received the permissions yet.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review